# Mata error 3204

Tags: syntax, stata

I am unsure why I am getting an error.

I think it may stem from a misunderstanding around the structure syntax, but I am not certain if this is the issue (it would be unsurprising if there are multiple issues).

I am emulating code (from William Gould's The Mata Book) in which the input is a scalar, but the input for the program I am writing is a colvector.

The objective of this exercise is to create a square matrix from a column vector (according to some rules) and once created, multiply this square matrix by itself.

The code is the following:

```
*! spatial_lag version 1.0.0

version 15
set matastrict on
//--------------------------------------------------------------
local SL                struct laginfo

local RS                real scalar
local RC                real colvector
local RM                real matrix
//--------------------------------------------------------------
mata

`SL'
{
    //-------------------inputs:
    `RC'    v
    //-------------------derived:
    `RM'    W
    `RM'    W2
    `RS'    n
}

void lagset(`RC' v)
{
    `SL' scalar r
    // Input:
    r.v     =   v
    //I set the derived variables to missing:
    r.W     =   .z  
    r.W2    =   .z  
    r.n     =   .z  // length of vector V
}

`RM' w_mat(`SL' scalar r)
{
    if (r.W == .z) {
        real scalar row, i
        real scalar col, j
        r.W = J(r.n,r.n,0)
        for (i=1; i<=r.n; i++) {
            for (i=1; i<=r.n; i++) {
                if (j!=i) {
                    if (r.v[j]==r.v[i]) {
                        r.W[i,j] = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return(r.W)
}

`RS' wlength(`SL' scalar r)
{
    if (r.n == .z) {
        r.n     =   length(r.v)
    }
    return(r.n)
}

`RM' w2mat(`SL' scalar r)
{
    if (r.W2 == .z) {
        r.W2    =   r.W * r.W
    }
    return(r.W2)
}
end
```

This compiles without a problem, but it give an error when I attempt to use it interactively as follows:

```
y=(1\1\1\2\2\2)
q = lagset(y)
w_mat(q)
w2mat(q)
```

The first two lines run fine, but when I run the last two of those lines, I get:

```
         w_mat():  3204  q[0,0] found where scalar required
         <istmt>:     -  function returned error
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: For starters and off the top of my head, it seems that `lagset` does not return anything. So what is `q` that is used as input in `w_mat`?

Comment: Yes, that does change things. I replaced the beginning of that function with: ` `SL' scalar lagset(`RC' v) ' and included the line at the end `return(r) '. This changes the error to something else, which I will try to troubleshoot. Conceptually, I think the thing I don't really understand is what "r" is and why it is scalar (which seems to be what is done). It does make sense now that I'd need to return it though, after defining the values.

I'm also not sure I understand all of your question. I thought I was defining q as equal to lagset(y). Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: My question was meant to be a hint. The point being that when nothing is returned from `lagset`, `q` ends up being `[0,0]`.

Comment: For your other question see [this article](https://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0035).

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Section 5 of the article answers my question; it is also related to the dimensionality of the object. It appears that the instance is not necessarily a "scalar" in the math sense of the word, but it needs to have positive dimension to be read by Mata.

Comment: I will consider the question answered, if you want to post an answer for me to accept. Fixing that showed me another error that I need to address, which I haven't figured out, but I think it's different enough that it makes sense for it to be a new question linking to this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular error is unrelated to structures. Stata simply complains because the `lagset()` function is *void*. That is, it does not return anything. Thus, `q` ends up being empty, which is in turn used as input in the function `w_mat()` inappropriately - hence the `q[0,0]` reference.